# Implementing ADOT for embedded metrics in AWS Lambda containers - any guidance?

Tags: aws-lambda, open-telemetry, aws-lambda-containers

Currently, we are conducting tests on ADOT within a lambda container to gather traces, and the results have been satisfactory. However, we have not discovered a definitive method for collecting embedded metrics specifically for lambda. Our objective is to eliminate the need for simultaneously running the CloudWatch agent and ADOT collector within the container.

If anyone has achieved a successful implementation of ADOT in a lambda container, we would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance.

Going through the documentation we didn't find clear implementation for aws lambda container image embedded metrics

Thank you